# Dojo Dijits Layout with ArcGIS SDK for Javascript

Tags: javascript, sdk, dojo, arcgis, dijit.layout

I'm trying to use Dojo Dijits Border Container and Content Pane with a Tiled Imagery Layer.  I can get the code to work to display just the Tiled Imagery Layer and also get it to work fine with the Dojo Dijits layout.  My problem is when I combine them into one unified code, all of the original styling is removed and I do not see the layer I am loading.  I had luck getting the two to merge together when I was using version 4.22, though when using version 4.27, I seem to be running into issues. I need it to run with the 4.27 so I can use some widgets that require that version.

I attached the code I have thus far.  When I include the last portion of the Javascript, my layout gets shifted and I loose most of the original formatting.  Any ideas on how to resolve this?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo: Layout with Dijit</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" media="screen">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"
            data-dojo-config="async:true, parseOnLoad:true"> </script>
   

</head>
<body class="claro">
    <div id="appLayout" class="demoLayout" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="design: 'headline'">
        <div class="centerPanel" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region: 'center'">
              <div id="viewDiv"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="edgePanel" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region: 'top'">Header content (top)
    </div>

    <div id="leftCol" class="edgePanel" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region: 'left', splitter: true">Sidebar content (left)
    </div>

    </div>

</body>
  
  
<!-- -----------------------------------CSS-------------------------------------------- -->  
<style>
    html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;}

  #viewDiv {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);}
  
#appLayout {
    height: 100%;}
#leftCol {
    width: 14em;}

.claro .demoLayout .edgePanel {
    background-color: #d0e9fc;}

#viewsChart {
    width: 550px;
    height: 550px;}
  
    
</style>
    
<!-- --------------------------------JAVASCRIPT---------------------------------------- -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.27/esri/themes/light/main.css" /> 
  <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.27/"></script> 
  
  <script>
   require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/TabContainer",
        "dijit/layout/ContentPane"]);
  </script>

  <script>
    require([
      "esri/Map",
      "esri/views/MapView",
      "esri/layers/ImageryTileLayer", // Import ImageryLayer module
      "esri/widgets/TimeSlider",
      "esri/widgets/Expand",
      "esri/widgets/Legend"
    ], (Map, MapView, ImageryTileLayer, TimeSlider, Expand, Legend) => {
      // Create an ImageryLayer using the Image Service URL
      const raster = new ImageryTileLayer({
        url:
         "https://tiledimageservices9.arcgis.com/6EuFgO4fLTqfNOhu/arcgis/rest/services/76_CRF/ImageServer"
      });

      const map = new Map({
        basemap: "gray-vector",
        layers: [raster]
      });

      const view = new MapView({
        map: map,
        container: "viewDiv",
        zoom: 11,
        center: [-121.6555, 36.6777]
      });
   });   
      </script>
<!-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->   
  
</html>
```